# Insert a web link to Mac OS X package installation in PackageMaker

Tags: installation, macos, packagemaker

I am using PakageMaker.app to create an installation package for Mac OS X and I'd like to insert a web link to my site on the *Introduction* screen of the installation. Is there any way to do this because I have not find any instruction about it in the docs?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer my question myself. To add link to package UI like on the image below 
[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/580e6fb18f.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/580e6fb18f.png)

you need to create rtf file with the text and links you want to have and then just in the interface editor add that file.